# Selenium Assert questions - Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, assert

How are you?

I'm starting with selenium, and I'm trying hard to deal with ***"AssertTrue (boolean condition)"***, but there's something wrong.

I need the Junit gets green(ok) if I access successfully one page, and I want it get red(nok) if it's not possible to access.

But all I got is Green, every single time!

For example: 
If I access the payment page it's ok (I assert that there's a buy button to be sure is the payment page)
If I try to access without being logged then the system displays an error message (If I do not find that buy button I won't be in the payment page)

So here's what I'm trying to do in the end of my public boolean method:

```
if(buybutton.isDisplayed()){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

So in my test class I'm trying to assert:

***Shoes*** is what I'm buying, and the **Shoeslink.com** is where I can find it. I put this two variables there because there's an **IF** - if the user wants to buy shoes selenium will expect some elements, if is a shirt selenium will expect others. But I guess it doesn't matter, because the assert is defined by the code I put above, right? And below is the assertcode I'm talking about:

```
assertTrue(buy.AccessProduct("**Shoes**", "**Shoeslink.com**"));
```

Well, if you guys have another logic or way to do it, that's all I need by now: A successfull test if I find an element or an error test if I don't.

Thank you!

Comment: Your `if(buybutton.isDisplayed())` code block can be simplified to `return buybutton.isDisplayed()`. It's not an answer, just something I noticed that can be simplified.

Comment: You probably need to share more of your code... at least some portions of `AccessProduct()` so we can see the logic and why it might be failing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you wrongly wrote parameters of assertTrue:

```
assertTrue("Error Message in case of false", buy.AccessProduct("**Shoes**", "**Shoeslink.com**"));
```

Comment: It is possible to call `assertTrue` with just a `boolean` as the first argument, as a 2 second Google search [shows](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)).